# Validate field only letters jquery/ajax

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, validation

I'm trying to validate a field which only allows letters. If I write a number or another sign the whole field will turn red and I wont be able to click on the "submit" button. That button will be locked until everything is OK.

A guy gave me this :

```js
$("#form-description").on("keyup", function() {
  var text = $(this).val();
  var a = 120 - text.length;
  var lettersonly = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
  if (!/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/.test(text)) {
    $(this).parent().css("border", "1px solid red");
  }
  $("#error-description").text(a), a < 10 && $("#charcount").css({
    color: "red"
  })
});
$('#herter').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 9) { //9 is tab key, 13 is enter key
    var text = $(this).val();
    if (text.length > 50) {
      alert("You have entered too much text. The maximum for this field is 50 characters.")
    } else if (text.length < 1) {
      alert("Please enter some text.");
    }

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><input type='text' class="form-text" id='herter' maxlength="60" name='txtnombre' required /><span class="error-form" id="error-name"></span></td>
<td>
  <div>
    <input type='text' class="form-text" id="form-description" name="txtdescripcion" />
  </div>

  <span class="error-form" id="error-description"></span></td>
<div id="charcount">
</div>
```

If I write a number the field turns red BUT it does not disappear when I delete everything on the field.. or for example if I write "Hello word4" if I delete the number 4 the field stays red :/.

It must show an alert if you write a number and it must validate each field using TAB key or clicking on the field

Also the submit button is not locked, if the field is "red" the submit button still works :/.

Dont know what to do :S

Comment: So, to be clear you want it so that anything EXCEPT letter will invalidate the field? Also, just so that I offer a suggestion, what if rather than invalidating the field you simply made it erase anything that was not a letter from the input making it so a user simply couldn't enter anything that isn't a number into the field.

Comment: What do you say?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you get in the right direction. This will add the "error" class to any input with the class "validate". After a field has been validated the doValidation will look for any errors. If it find errors the button is disabled if none are found it will enable the button again. Fairly straight forward.

```js
let doValidation = (field) => {
  // Check for the amount of none letter chars
  if(field.value.replace(/[A-z]/g,"").length)
    // If found add error
    $(field).addClass('error');
  else
    // If none found ensure no error
    $(field).removeClass('error');
  
  // Check total input errors
  if($('.error').length)
    // If some are found disable button
    $('input[type=button]').attr('disabled','true');
  else
    // If none are found enable button
    $('input[type=button]').removeAttr('disabled');
}

// Runs when field is clicked or focus is lost (Tab)
$('.validate').on('click focusout',function(){
  doValidation(this);
});
```

```css
.error {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="validate">
<input type="text" class="validate">

<input type="button" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Dude, what should i put in "field"?

Comment: You don't need to put anything in there. When the user does a click or focusout action that event passes the `this` object and the `doValidate` function validates that specific field. You can run the snippet and see it function live. :-)

Comment: Take a look pal,it is not working in my program, what's wrong?
https://ideone.com/ePEDdj

Comment: You added all the code under the </html> tag. It has to be at least in the body. The link you sent me has like 100 errors (at least that is the readout at the bottom) that are unrelated to the validation that you are requesting. Please fix the sample without the validation that I gave you and we can start from there.

Comment: The program works properly, it shows error because it is incompleted.. i only sent you the "file" which contains the validation:
I changed the position of the scripts but is still not working :/]
https://ideone.com/58fAA5